# Cannot link to sublibrary/internal library/embedded library with CMake's Visual Studio generator

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, cmake

The [full error is available at AppVeyor](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/vinipsmaker/boost-http/build/1.0.44/job/n0aravdx3fn6mcec#L752).

I create a library using CMake's `add_library` command, but when I try to compile another target to this library, I get silly errors like `LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\Debug\boost_http.lib' [C:\projects\boost-http\build\test\algorithm.vcxproj]`.

Other CMake generators do fine.

How to properly handle this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your other question, I gather the project is [this one](https://github.com/vinipsmaker/asiohttpserver/tree/travis).

The cause of the problem is that you're building `boost_http` as a shared library, but you don't export any functions or classes from it.  You need to decorate the public API functions/classes with `__declspec(dllexport)` to make these available to consuming targets.  See the [Microsoft docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a90k134d%28v=vs.140%29.aspx) for further info.

If you do that, you'll find that as well as boost_http.dll there will be a small file called boost_http.lib which is what consuming targets will actually link to.  This is what your tests are being told to link to, but it doesn't exist.

CMake's [GenerateExportHeader](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/module/GenerateExportHeader.html) can help in this regard.  There is a description of how to use it in [the wiki](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/BuildingWinDLL).

However, an easier fix would be to just make the `boost_http` target static.  By changing to `add_library("boost_http" STATIC ${library_SRC})`, the project should work as is.

Comment: I made the suggested changes (lot of pain for a small change) and it [generated the .lib file](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/vinipsmaker/boost-http/build/1.0.56/job/nv95rdvf8ky9h2p9#L1485). Thank you.